# Sum of individual labels over a month of granular data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe which contains life logging data gathered over several years from 44 unique individuals.

```
Int64Index: 77171 entries, 0 to 4279
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   start      77171 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   end        77171 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 2   labelName  77171 non-null  category      
 3   id         77171 non-null  int64
```

The `start` column contains granular datetimes of the format `2020-11-01 11:00:00`, in  intervals of 30 minutes. The `labelName` column has 14 different categories.

```
Categories (14, object): ['COOK', 'EAT', 'GO WALK', 'GO TO BATHROOM', ..., 'DRINK', 'WAKE UP', 'SLEEP', 'WATCH TV']
```

Here's a sample user's head, which is `[2588 rows x 4 columns]` and spans from 2020 to 2021. There are also gaps in the data, occasionally.

```
                  start                 end       labelName   id
0   2020-08-05 00:00:00 2020-08-05 00:30:00  GO TO BATHROOM  486
1   2020-08-05 06:00:00 2020-08-05 06:30:00         WAKE UP  486
2   2020-08-05 09:00:00 2020-08-05 09:30:00            COOK  486
3   2020-08-05 11:00:00 2020-08-05 11:30:00             EAT  486
4   2020-08-05 12:00:00 2020-08-05 12:30:00             EAT  486
..                  ...                 ...             ...  ...
859 2021-03-10 12:30:00 2021-03-10 13:00:00  GO TO BATHROOM  486
861 2021-03-10 13:30:00 2021-03-10 14:00:00  GO TO BATHROOM  486
862 2021-03-10 18:30:00 2021-03-10 19:00:00            COOK  486
864 2021-03-11 08:00:00 2021-03-11 08:30:00             EAT  486
865 2021-03-11 12:30:00 2021-03-11 13:00:00            COOK  486
```

I want a sum of each unique `labelNames` per user per month, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I would first split the data frame by `id`, which is easy. But how do you split these `start` datetimes when it records every 30 minutes over several years of data— and then create 14 new columns which record the sums?

The final data frame might look something like this (with fake values):

| user | month | SLEEP | ... | WATCH TV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 486 | jun20 | 324 | ... | 23 |
| 486 | jul20 | 234 | ... | 12 |

The use-case for this data frame is training a few statistical and machine-learning models.

How do I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are 30 minutes data you can count them by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) per months by months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then multiple by `0.5` for output in hours:

*If start is `2020-09-30 23:30:00` and end is `2020-10-01 00:00:00` then if need count this record for October use `df['end']` in `crosstab`, if for September use `df['start']` .*

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

df1 = (pd.crosstab([df['id'], df['end'].dt.to_period('m')], df['labelName']).mul(0.5)
        .rename_axis(columns=None, index=['id','month'])
        .rename(columns=str)
        .reset_index()
        .assign(month=lambda x:x['month'].dt.strftime('%b%Y')))
print (df1)
    id    month  COOK  EAT  GO TO BATHROOM  SLEEP  WAKE UP
0  650  Sep2020   0.0  0.0             1.0    0.5      1.0
1  650  Mar2021   0.5  1.0             0.5    0.5      0.0
```

For ouput in 30 minutes:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

df = (pd.crosstab([df['id'], df['end'].dt.to_period('m')], df['labelName'])
        .rename_axis(columns=None, index=['id','month'])
        .reset_index()
        .assign(month=lambda x:x['month'].dt.strftime('%b%Y')))
print (df)

    id    month  COOK  EAT  GO TO BATHROOM  SLEEP  WAKE UP
0  650  Sep2020     0    0               2      1        2
1  650  Mar2021     1    2               1      1        0
```

Comment: This is going to sound strange but it worked on the first run, then when I restarted my Kernel and reran everything I get a TypeError: 'fill_value=month' is not present in this Categorical's categories.

Comment: @tsainez - can you try add `.rename(columns=str)` ?

Comment: that worked, but why are there values such as 0.5? is this a sum?

Comment: @tsainez - because without it ouput is e.g. 2 times 30minutes, 1 for 30minutes, 3 for 3 times 30 minutes. So seems better ouoput in hours, so multiple 0.5 - so if 2 times 30 minutes it is 1 hour, 1 for 30 minutes is 0.5 hour.

Comment: @tsainez - if need ouput in count by 30 minutes only remove `mul(0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from collections import Counter
df.groupby([df['start'].dt.to_period('M'), 'id'])['labelName'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x)).reset_index().pivot_table('labelName', ['id', 'start'], 'level_2', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

[image]

Demonstration:

```
#Preparing Data
string = """start  end  labelName  id
2020-09-21 14:30:00  2020-09-21 15:00:00  WAKE UP  650
2020-09-21 15:00:00  2020-09-21 15:30:00  GO TO BATHROOM  650
2020-09-21 15:30:00  2020-09-21 16:00:00  SLEEP  650
2020-09-29 17:00:00  2020-09-29 17:30:00  WAKE UP  650
2020-09-29 17:30:00  2020-09-29 18:00:00  GO TO BATHROOM  650
2021-03-11 13:00:00  2021-03-11 13:30:00  EAT  650
2021-03-11 14:30:00  2021-03-11 15:00:00  GO TO BATHROOM  650
2021-03-11 15:00:00  2021-03-11 15:30:00  COOK  650
2021-03-11 15:30:00  2021-03-11 16:00:00  EAT  650
2021-03-11 16:00:00  2021-03-11 16:30:00  SLEEP  650"""
data = [x.split('  ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])

#Solution
from collections import Counter
df.groupby([df['start'].dt.to_period('M'), 'id'])['labelName'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x)).reset_index().pivot_table('labelName', ['id', 'start'], 'level_2', fill_value=0)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be able to differentiate by month— I updated the sample I provided for some more context

Comment: Sorry, Edited the answer.

Comment: All the years get clumped together into the same month— so December 2020 and December 2022 are summed together, but they should be distinct.

Comment: Just use df['start'].dt.to_period('M') instead for grouping. Edited the answer.